# Using jQuery to change a different element on hover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to change my images when the button is hovered, I found an incredibly helpful post on here... but my method isn't working.

(Forgive me, I'm new to jQuery). I need the pictures to swap when the button is hovered. Below is what I've tried so far:

```js
           $("#green-btn") // select your element (supports CSS selectors)
    .hover(function(){ // trigger the mouseover event
        $("#pic2") // select the element to show (can be anywhere)
            .show(); // show the element
    }, function(){ // trigger the mouseout event
        $("#pic1") // select the same element
            .hide(); // hide it
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




<div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <h1 class="mb-3">hello</h1>

<button id="green-btn" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary mt-4">Start your free trial</button>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
<img id="pic1" style="display: width:100vh;height: 90vh;" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">

<img id="pic2" style="display:none; width:100vh;height: 90vh;" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x100"></div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So a couple things.  First off, your jquery include needs to be before your bootstrap include.  Also, your hover methods are not toggling the visibility of the elements.  The hover over (first method) is only showing the second pic, and the hover out (second method) is only hiding the first pic.  Neither method is reverting these changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake ("display: width:100vh;..."):

```
<img id="pic1" style="display: block; width:100vh;height: 90vh;" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
```

and if you only want to toggle, use toggle() function.

```
$("#green-btn")
.hover(function() { 
    $("#pic2, #pic1").toggle(); 
}, function() {
    $("#pic1, #pic2").toggle();
});
```

There is a difference between hover in (move cursor on element) and hover out (move cursor away from element). Example above: First function runs while hovering on element and the second function if you hovering out.

If you only want to change picture by hover in (so mouseover), then remove the second function and use mouseover():

```
$("#green-btn")
    .mouseover(function() { 
        $("#pic2, #pic1").toggle(); 
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not toggling both the pictures properly. `#pic2` is always shown when hover begins, and `#pic1` is always hidden when hover ends.

You need to correctly toggle the images like below:

```js
$("#green-btn") // select your element (supports CSS selectors)
  .hover(function() { // trigger the mouseover event
    $("#pic2") // select the element to show (can be anywhere)
      .show(); // show the element
    $("#pic1") // select the element to show (can be anywhere)
      .hide();
  }, function() { // trigger the mouseout event
    $("#pic1") // select the same element
      .show(); // hide it
    $("#pic2") // select the same element
      .hide(); // hide it
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>





<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h1 class="mb-3">hello</h1>

      <button id="green-btn" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary mt-4">Start your free trial</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img id="pic1" style="display: width:100vh;height: 90vh;" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">

      <img id="pic2" style="display:none; width:100vh;height: 90vh;" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```